# where is the Android 4.3 examples?

Tags: android

I have downloaded the `SDK ADT Bundle for Windows` at http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Unzip the package,But I have not found the examples.I am a newbie.Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: `<android-sdk-root-folder>/samples/android-18`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you have downloaded the "Samples for SDK" item which is located under Android 4.3 (API18) using the SDK Manager. As far as I know, current bundles comes with API17 files and they don't contain "Samples for SDK" item for this api level either.
2. Then the samples are located in "\samples\android-18".

Note: A little more detailed explanation about samples can be found at http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html, if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks.But there is no "Samples for SDK" item under  Android 4.3 (API18).I have added the image to my question.

Comment: Probabaly you don't have any internet connection or there is a connection problem on your computer. Check your internet connection and reopen the sdk manager(or you can reload packages from "Packages" menu by selecting "Reload").

Comment: internet connection well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download it using the SDK manager.